# what If I did a fresh install of 17.04 and still keep Swap partition?

Tags: swap, 17.04

what If I did a fresh install of 17.04 and still choose to keep `/swap` partition by manually making it instead of swap files.

what advantages or disadvantages I'll be looking at?

in short **Swap files vs Swap partition that is equal to the size of RAM**

Comment: I have always set up a swap partition in all of the linux distros I have tried over the years and believe that is the way to go. Remember, swap as RAM is dynamic (active, MUCH file I/O) and separating the space in which that work is done is better all the way around. I have even done this in some Windows installs with good results.

Comment: @Craig yeah, I mean I've been using Swap Partition too, But now I can't figure out what to do in Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: took a look online and found some info that should be helpful for you. look at this link  - https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space - should be helpful.